# Magento 1.9 - Check if the user is on the checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Is there a way I can check if the user is on the checkout/onepage page and display something. I have tried the below but for some reason it doesn't equal true on the checkout page

```
<?php if($this->getUrl('checkout/onepage') == Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()): ?>
    On checkout page
        <?php else: ?>
            not on checkout page
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Where did you add this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code if you are using default magento 1 checkout:

```
<?php $handles = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles(); ?>
<?php if(in_array('checkout_onepage_index',$handles)): ?>
    // your code
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
  * get Controller name
 */
  $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();

/**
 * get Action name, i.e. the function inside the controller
*/
 $this->getRequest()->getActionName();

  /**
   * get Router name
 */
  $this->getRequest()->getRouteName();

 /**
  * get module name
 */
  $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();

 /**
 * get namespace & module name
 * for example, if you are in checkout page 
 * then, this will return Mage_Checkout
 */
 $this->getRequest()->getControllerModule();
```